# How to set variable values in parent class only for specific child class in C#?

Tags: c#

I have 3 classes A, B and C.

```
class A
{
    protected string name="demo";
}

class B: A
{}

class C: A
{}
```

I want to set the value of name as "demo1" in parent class A only for the child class C and not for B.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: As an aside, most likely it is a XY problem and the design could be changed in order to prevent all of this. The purpose of access modifier `protected` is to *allow* child classes to change the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a constructor to `A` that allows you to set the value:

```
class A
{
    private string name="demo";

    public A() {}

    public A(string name)
    {
      this.name = name;
    }
}

class B: A
{}

class C: A
{
  public C() : base("demo1")
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should put `name="demo"` as default value in `A` constructor, you won't have to send the string when creating `A` and `B` instances.

Answer (score 2):

Because in your code, A has a private field, no other class can see or modify it.

If you make the field protected, this means it is visible to itself and to classes that derive from it, but not visible from outside the classes.

```
class A
{
    protected string name="demo";
}

class B: A
{}

class C: A
{
    C()
    {
       name = "ClassC";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I set the value for class C variable inside Class A itself?

Answer (score 1):

Could you have them all implement that same interface and have class C inherit from class A but class B only implements the interface.  It's all a little vague so hard to tell the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Using inheritance, the simplest solution would put the specified variable in another class that inherits from A and will be only inherited by C (while B still directly inherits from A).

```
class A
{}

class B: D
{}

class C: A
{}

class D: A 
{
    protected string name="demo";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
{
    protected virtual string name="demo";
}

class B: A
{}

class C: A
{
   protected override string name="demo1";
}
```